# Excel VBA: For a variable number of rows between two identifiers, search each of a variable number of columns for a string

Tags: vba, search, excel

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a spreadsheet that contains a variable number of rows that are each of variable length.

The range in which the rows are contained is marked at the beginning and end by an identifier in column A formatted like so: "#Description"

As mentioned, the length of each row (length here = number of columns) is variable. For each row, I need to loop through each column and determine if it contains a user-defined string.

I have tried creating a Range between the two identifiers and then a range that extends to the end of the longest row, but searching yields no results.

```
Set firstDesc = ws.Range("A1:A9999").Find("# Description:")
Set secDesc = ws.Range("A1:A9999").Find("# Description:", firstDesc)
Set searchArea = ws.Range(secDesc, secDesc.End(xlToRight))

'grab the name of the node
   Dim nodeName As String
   nodeName = TextBox1.Value

'Find occurences of the node entered by user
   Set Node = searchArea.Find(nodeName)
   If Not Node Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Value Found in Cell " & Node.Address
   End If
```

Comment: You may want to check for whitespace and possibly remove it before performing the search.

Comment: try searching the entire worksheet via VBA once... it will diagnose whether your problem is with the defined range, or the search itself (did you specify correct parameters like Match Case, look in Formulas/Values, etc)

Comment: If you have empty cells in the `secDesc` range `secDesc.End(xlToRight)` could be giving you a smaller search Range than you expect.

Comment: Set breakpoints in your code and check things like the size of the search Range (as @bernie) suggests. I'd also suggest doing this on a smaller sample set of data to ensure things are functioning correctly, then apply it to your real data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the following parameters in your the `Range.Find` method: `LookAt` (xlPart or xlWhole) and `LookIn` (xlValues or xlFormulas). There are no default values for these parameters; these settings are saved every time you use `Range.Find` method.